# Android :Text Animation

Tags: android

I am working in android.. i want to move my text in animation.

this is the xml code which i am using:-

```
android:shareInterpolator="true">

 <translate android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="-80%p"

android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" 

android:duration="2000" />
```

```
    android:pivotX="-70%p" android:pivotY="10%p" android:duration="1000"

    android:startOffset="2000" />
```

```
android:fromXDelta="0%p" android:toXDelta="80%p"

android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="0%p" android:duration="2000"

android:startOffset="3000" />
```

Using above xml my TEXT is moving in this shape:-
[image]

But i want to move my text into this following way:-
[image]

means i want to move my text into **Z** format. please suggest me how should write xml code for this. You can provide me some links for this. if you can code this then this will be very great help for me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the following works for me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="80%p"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="2000"/>
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-80%p"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="80%p"
        android:duration="1000" android:startOffset="2000"/>
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="80%p"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="2000" android:startOffset="3000"/>
</set>
```

Comment: @jave i need one help. how to change the image when load the second translate.? pls help me

Comment: @Ganesh you would need a second listener that after `2000`millis changed the image

Answer (score 5):

you can do this by using following steps.

1.create a animation.xml

2.put this code in this animation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:shareInterpolator="true">
    <translate
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="80%p"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="2000"/>
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-80%p"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p" android:toYDelta="80%p"
        android:duration="1000" android:startOffset="2000"/>
    <translate 
        android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="80%p"
        android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
        android:duration="2000" android:startOffset="3000"/>
</set>
```

put this file into res/anim folder of your application.

write following code for your textview on which you want to make animation.

```
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.animation);

        animation.setAnimationListener(this);

        View animatedView = findViewById(R.id.textview);

          animatedView.startAnimation(animation);
```

I hope now you can understand this easily .